# smbinning function is not working in R

Tags: r

I have data frame of 49346 rows and 709 columns.
But when I try to apply smbinning function of smbinning package,

```
smbinning(df=dfrm[1:49346, ], x="v1", y="Target") #it's working
smbinning(df=dfrm           , x="v1", y="Target") #this is not working
```

nrow(dfrm) result is 49346 and str() etc every outputs point out that
dfrm has 49346 rows,
However, the second line makes error like below

> Error in . cnode(1L, data, infl, inputs, weights, ctrl) :
>        R_expCovLinstat : y does not have 49346 rows

Answer (score 0):

I figured out difference between two cases. dfrm[1:49346, ] had no attribute like labels so it was working, but just dfrm had labels so it was not working. After I delete labels from dfrm, it worked.